# allow htaccess redirect in nginx server

Tags: .htaccess, nginx

Here is my htaccess file in nginx server but not working
i want to run index.html like following url

```
http://domain.com//folder1/folder2/?a=af.jpg
```

```
   <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /folder1/folder2/
    #Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
    #such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
    #request to index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.html?/$1 

   </IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following rule:

```
location /folder1/folder2/ {
  if (!-e $request_filename){
    rewrite ^/folder1/folder2/(.*)$ /folder1/folder2/index.html?/$1;
  }
}
```

Comment: Ok, so for prosperity, no, nginx does not have .htaccess support, and this should really be fine with try_files.